# Is there a way to load external Angular2 Module / Component in a running application ?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I was wondering if someone already loaded a compiled angular2 module or component into a running application during runtime.

For exemple, when i click on a specific button the app find the right JS file to load, load it and then append the component to the page or redirect the user to a specific url defined in this imported module...

Comment: Are you talking about a different component in the same project or a different project altogether?

Comment: I'd like to include independent component develop by other developer based on specifications (other project component but with comon hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha. Well one way is to include the project of your external components by defining dev dependency in package.json.

The dependency could point to a git repository or a local project. Once you have defined the dependency, doing a npm install should include the project in your node modules.

Comment: That's was our first idea, but it require all app compilation to work. I was wondering if module could have been build separately and hot loaded during app runtime

Comment: The idea behind this is that uses access a kind of store of module and activate every module they needs. After activation the app may have a different behavior